# Do disassemblers detect standard functions?

Tags: reverse-engineering, assembly

Do disassemblers detect the use of C/C++ standard functions and specify them in the output code, adding the `#include` line to the appropriate header file (such as `stdio.h` or even `windows.h`)?

If not, does the whole big library is being recognized as the developer's own business-logic code, and written fully? Aren't the standard libraries known binary sequences (or can be processed some way to be known, as a binary-code can be different because of addressing)?

Do you know disassemblers that do detect standard functions and properly #include them in the output?

Comment: Don't cross-post. [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/218628/do-disassemblers-detect-standard-functions), [reverseengineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/do-disassemblers-detect-standard-functions)

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear to me, but I'll try to answer as I understand it,

Yes, disassemblers do detect standard functions which is possibly loaded as dynamically linkable library (dll) into memory when you execute the binary.

The standard library functions (esp. those that belong to stdio/iostream/stdlib etc) are generally part of most operating system distribution, which is not shipped with debugging symbols (meaning, you won't be able to see the human readable source code, but would still be able to see the assembly level instructions) as a dynamically linkable library. So, if you wan't to see the source code of the functions that belong to standard library, then you need a debug build of the dynamically linkable library, which will include symbol related information with mapping of source code line numbers.